# Experimental JUnit support in Android + Kotlin not working

Tags: android, junit, kotlin

Google recently released [experimental](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) support for running junit on local JVM in Android Studio. I wanted to try it out and since I am developing my Android app using Kotlin I want my tests classes be written in Kotlin too.

Unfortunately, I can't make it working.
I have updated my gradle configuration:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'//this line was added
}
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
```

Android Studio recognise test folder.

This is my simple test class just to see if it works

```
public class MyFirstTestClass {

    [Test] fun firstTest() {
        println("I am OK")
        Assert.assertTrue("".isEmpty())
    }
}
```

If I try to run it I get the following message

> Class not found: 'com.example.MyFirstTestClass'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatly, kotlin-gradle plugin doesn't support Junit tests for Android at this moment.

EDIT: Junit support for android was added in Kotlin M12

Comment: For completeness, you can still use Java based unit tests to test your Kotlin classes.

Comment: is there any way to auto-generate a java junit test for a kotlin class? **Go To -> Test** is greyed out for me unfortunately for **.kt** classes

Comment: In [Kotlin Beta 1 RC announcement](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/10/kotlin-1-0-beta-candidate-is-out/) it was mentioned that "The last but not least, unit testing experience is much smoother now. List of improvements: “Create Test” action, tests are runnable via gutter icons, navigation between tests and test subjects (⇧⌘T/⇧^T) and also quickfixes to add dependencies on JUnit and TestNG when needed"   ... which gives you those features you are looking for with navigating unit tests.  @ZakTaccardi